# How do I determine the size of a DB instance? (Sybase 12.5)

Tags: sybase

I've got an instance with dozens of DB's, and I need to know the total spaced used by all the DB's.  I don't want to have to do sp_spaceused on each of them.  Could I do a foreach loop and add them all up, or something like that?  Or is there some system stored proc that will do the job?

Answer (score 1):

If the DBs are on their own partitions, `df -h` will return the information under *nix. If they're in their own directories, you can run `du -hS`.

Not sure how you'd do it *inside* Sybase itself, though.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that approach...  Thanks Warren!